# How to apply texture the same size on all meshes? ignore mesh\normal size

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to apply texture to the wall in "Generated - Cube" mode and when i look at it in the Render mode - it has different scales on the different meshes which have different size. The same thing goes with the polygons - smaller polygons scale texture size.

If one of the polygon's dimensions has a very tiny size - texture looks totally wasted.

How to apply texture on meshes with the different size and ignore it's size for texture scale?

*p.s. Blender render*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that's a solution for Cycles Render, not Blender Render: Try some parameters in the Image Texture node, like Box instead of Flat:

[image]

Comment: That works fine when it comes to one mesh, thank you. Even it's not the Blender render that i use.  
So I would accept this as the solution but with the addition: when you need to apply this on many meshes with different size - choose "Object" not "Generated" in the Texture coordinate node. And select the mesh with the texture scale that you desire as a role model for others.

Comment: oh sorry I skipped you used Blender Render